# Need to get the Installed ODBC Driver details

Tags: c#, mysql, odbc, driver, mysql-odbc-connector

mySql and Oracle drivers in odbc to connect my application.By Now i need to get the connected driver details. (Ie) if am connecting a sql datatbase in odbc,how to find that its an SQL similarly for mySql and Oracle. 
**By using this i can only get the DSN Name,Not the driver type or driver details**

```
 reg = reg.OpenSubKey("ODBC");
        if (reg != null)
        {
            reg = reg.OpenSubKey("ODBC.INI");
            if (reg != null)
            {
                reg = reg.OpenSubKey("ODBC Data Sources");
                if (reg != null)
                {
                    // Get all DSN entries defined in DSN_LOC_IN_REGISTRY.
                        foreach (string sName in reg.GetValueNames())
                        {Messagebox.Show(sName);
                        }
                }
            }
        }
```

**NOTE**:I can get the dll name in opened connection by its connection extension DRIVER but it is giving the driver's dll name only.But i need to identify the driver type wether the connection is a SQL or MySQL od ORACLE ..??

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible. Have a look for example at drivers for Microsoft Access/dBase/Excel. They all use the same DLL, in my case `C:\PROGRA~2\COMMON~1\MICROS~1\OFFICE14\ACEODBC.DLL`

So, you cannot say a DLL connects to one single database server only.

Comment: so is there a way to find which driver type the connection belongs to in ODBC.

Answer (score 0):

If you have established a connection to a database using one of the DSN entries (or a connection-string) you can use the SQLGetInfo() Function to query various details about the driver or database, like SQL_DRIVER_NAME, etc.

But I dont know if this really helps you, as this needs an established connection to the database..

see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711681%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

You can use `SQLGetInfo()` with the argument `SQL_DBMS_NAME` to get the name of the Database Product. This will fill the buffer pointed to by `InfoValuePtr` with values like `Microsoft SQL Server` for SQLServer or `MySQL` for MySQL, etc. The exact value depends on the driver.

Comment: But my problem is ,how i know tat the established connection from DSN was a sql connection or mySQL connection..?